# Oven thermostat substitute?

Tags: thermostat, appliances, oven

I own an oven that uses a 2168 thermostat pictured here:
[image: oven thermostat] with a wiring diagram that looks like the one on the right:
[image: thermostat wiring diagram].  For reasons that I can't determine (mercury?), this thermostat is very hard or impossible to get, so I'm trying to find a similar one that I can use to replace the 2168.   At some point the manufacturer switched to a 2169  ([image: another thermostat]), but I can't tell if that one would work.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the limits of interchangibility -- I think I need a double pole 220 v 17 amp thermostat with at least a 30 inch capillary.  Anyone ever try going generic?  Any luck?  Any tips?   I'd hate to throw out a relatively lightly used stove because I can't buy a new thermostat.

Comment: Have you tried the manufacturer of the oven?  They should know what replacement parts fit.  Sometimes you can find a list that says which parts are good replacements, might need to try a few different search terms.

Comment: It appears that the 2nd picture (at least) comes from an appliance parts web site (BTW- it's expected that you list the sources of _all_ your images), have you looked at that site to see if the 2169 is listed as a replacement for the 2168? Every time I've looked for parts for tools or appliances online, there is a laundry list of "this part replaces: x, y, z, p, d, q..." for nearly every part I've needed. If it's not actually listed, most retailers have a "contact us" where they'd be able to tell you in the hopes of getting you to buy should you find a match.

Comment: There is no mercury in one of those.

Comment: @Freeman   called the mfr of the stove.  They changed to the 2169,  but they didn't say that it replaced the 2168, but only that they'd changed.  Trying to figure out if it is a replacement, or they rewired the interior to make it work.  It doesn't appear to have the same layout of terminals, but if it is just a switch with the same inputs, I could probably make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 6th try, I managed to find a new old stock thermostat.  I had to remove the face plate from the new one and replace it with the old one to get the screws to line up, but so far it appears to work.  I took the old one apart and it had a lot of very old school components.

I managed to find it at an online vendor of lawn mowing equipment -- Amazon, Ebay, the manufacturer of the stove, and  the manufacturer of the thermostat were all dead ends.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you can physically mount it to the oven, it has the appropriate terminals, and it's rated at or above the amperage required, it should work.

The terminals don't need to be **physically arranged** the same way. They do need to be **electrically connected** the same way.

You don't supply, and a quick web search also fails to supply a wiring diagram for the 2169 to verify that it offers the same terminals and switching from an electrical point of view as the 2168. You'll need to verify that by some means (buy from a place that will take returns, or find some place with the info listed as opposed to vague pictures of the part with no diagrams.)

Comment: What about the performance of the thermostat?   I've been fruitlessly searching for information on this for a while.